# How do I change the colors and line types of interaction plots in visreg

Tags: r, plot, regression, visualization

I'm relatively new to R, and I'm using the visreg package to plot an interaction. I can't figure out how to take the output plot, which defaults to plotting the relationship of x1 on y at the 10th, 50th, and 90th quantiles of x2, and change the colors to greyscale, and the three lines to three different line types (dotted, solid, twodash, etc.)

Here's my code:

```
    interaction <- lm(Y ~ X1 * X2, data=df)

    visreg(interaction,"X1", by="X2", 
    overlay = TRUE, partial = FALSE, rug = FALSE)
```

And here's what the plot looks like:

[image]
Thanks for your help.

N

Answer (score 5):

You can add `fill` and `line` arguments to `visreg` to change the colors and line types. These options don't seem to be well documented in the help, but the [`visreg` vignette](http://pbreheny.github.io/visreg/options.html) has an example (scroll down to "Appearance of points, lines, and bands").  Here's an example using the built-in `mtcars` data frame.

```
library(visreg)

interaction <- lm(mpg ~  hp*wt , data=mtcars)

visreg(interaction,"hp", by="wt", 
       fill=list(col=grey(c(0.2,0.5,0.8), alpha=0.4)),
       line=list(lty=1:3, col="black"),
       overlay = TRUE, partial = FALSE, rug = FALSE)
```

[image]

As another option, you can take the data returned by `visreg` and use it to create a ggplot to your specifications.

First, we create a visreg plot and assign it to an an object called `p`. `plot=FALSE` prevents the plot from being drawn. `p` contains a list of information invisibly returned by `visreg`. One element of that list, called `fit` contains the fit information we need for plotting, so we'll use that with `ggplot`.

I like this a bit better than the `visreg` plot, because (1) the lines can all be plotted on top of the confidence bands, so that they are not obscured by the confidence bands, and (2) you can add a subtle border to the confidence bands that makes them a bit easier to distinguish. I also prefer the ggplot legend.

I should point out that you can create the ggplot interaction plot directly from the data and model object, without using `visreg`, but `visreg` returns all the information we need without having to go through any extra coding.

```
library(ggplot2)

p = visreg(interaction,"hp", by="wt",
           overlay = TRUE, partial = FALSE, rug = FALSE,
           plot=FALSE)

ggplot(p$fit, aes(hp, visregFit, linetype=factor(wt), fill=factor(wt))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=visregLwr, ymax=visregUpr), alpha=0.5, 
              colour="grey50", linetype=1, size=0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_fill_grey(start=0.5, end=0.8) +
  labs(linetype="Weight", fill="Weight")
```

[image]